# js - Достать из json значения всех элементов "s" и склеить в строку

Tags: javascript, json

В запросе отсылаю текст на сервис проверки орфографии и он возвращает json такого формата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно достать все элементы **s[0]** и склеить их в строку получив такой вот результат: "привет друг"

Щас же через **console.log(totals)**; получаю **undefined**

А если пытаюсь так:

```js
    let totals = checkedData.s[0];
    console.log(totals);
```

То вылазит следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
    var checkRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    checkRequest.open('GET', 'https://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice.json/checkText?text=' + getTextFirst);
    checkRequest.send();

    checkRequest.onload = function () {
      if (checkRequest.readyState === checkRequest.DONE) {
        if (checkRequest.status === 200) {
          var checkedData = checkRequest.response;
          let totals = checkedData.s;
          console.log(totals);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншоту, вам возвращают массив. Т.е:

```
checkedData[0].s[0]
```

Comment: Вот что в консоли:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.checkRequest.onload (contentScript.js:193)

Comment: В оригинальном сообщении эта ошибка была вызвана тем, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к свойству `s` у массива `checkedData`. Если же у вас такая ошибка с моим вариантом, то напишите по-детальнее, что у вас в консоли если вы выводите checkedData.

Кстати, чтобы склеить все в одну строку, как вы пишете, самый простой способ был бы:

`checkedData.map(x=>x.s[0]).join(", ")`

Comment: Вот код на данный момент: https://prnt.sc/q9f84w

Вот что получаю в консоли: https://prnt.sc/q9f5x2

Answer (score 0):

Если `checkedData` содержит уже разобранный из JSON объект:

```
let totals = checkedData.map(entry => entry.s[0]).join(' ');
```

---

А вообще, удобнее через `fetch` (только не забудь про обработку ошибок), и маленькую деструктуризацию:

```js
const splCheck = txt => {
  const apiUri = 'https://speller.yandex.net/services/spellservice.json/checkText?text='; 
  return fetch(apiUri + encodeURIComponent(txt)).then(r => r.json()); 
}; 

const str = 'превет друх'; 
const checked = splCheck(str).then(data => {
  const result = data.map(({s}) => s[0]).join(' '); 
  console.log(result); 
});
```

Comment: Работает, но не так как бы хотелось. Если ввести два слова (корректное и нет) то в результате будет только исправленное слово в котором была ошибка, слово которое было написано правильно не отобразится. Так же если оба слова неправильны то отобразиться только первое из них

Comment: Вот код - https://prnt.sc/qh9odx 
В запрос почему то уходит только первое слово, но так не постоянно, не понимаю почему - https://prnt.sc/qh9oqf
Здесь первый лог - сообщение которое я отправил, второй лог - ответ (только одно слово) - https://prnt.sc/qh9ob2

Comment: @ДмитрийПензяков, Код в ответе решает задачу указанную в вопросе: _«достать все элементы s[0] и склеить их в строку получив такой вот результат: "привет друг"»_. Если возникли трудности с другой задачей - можно задать о них другой вопрос, подробно все описав. Подгонка кода в комментариях под непостоянные желания, не приносит пользы сообществу (вопрос и ответ должны касаться одной конкретной задачи/проблемы, чтобы можно было найти в поиске).

Comment: Тем более что я не изучал документацию этого сервиса Яндекса (неинтересно), и поэтому не знаю как с ним работать. А другие участники, которые работали с сервисом проверки орфографии и могли бы ответить на новый вопрос - не увидят его, так как он задан в комментариях...